# How can I check roles in Discord with a bot?

Tags: javascript, bots, roles, discord

I try to make the bot to respond differently at every role the server have but i cant seem to make it work. It doesn't give me any errors but it gives me the wrong answer.

```
client.on('message', message => 
{
  if(message.content === prefix + 'assist')
    if (message.member.roles.equals("344848334969765893"))
      {      
        message.reply("Ohhh a fellow rng player! May the rng be with you!");
      } 
    else 
      {
        message.reply("You do not have the Admin role.");
      }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To make it easier for people to help you, please format your code correctly. Either indent it with at least 4 spaces (multiple lines) **or** wrap it in back ticks (inline code). Also, try to mind your spelling when asking a question. Thank you!

Comment: Furthermore, please specify what exactly goes wrong when you run your code. Make sure to refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
member.roles.find('name', 'Admin')
```

As opposed to

```
member.member.roles.equals("344848334969765893")
```

or use

```
member.roles.get('344848334969765893')
```

since you already know the id. You can find the discord.js collection documentation on `find` [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find).

---

To answer more fully, for the logic you're doing, it would be like

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if(message.content === prefix + 'assist') {
    if (message.member.roles.get('344848334969765893'))
      {      
        message.reply("Ohhh a fellow rng player! May the rng be with you!");
      } 
    else 
      {
        message.reply("You do not have the Admin role.");
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: For some reason the

member.roles.get('344848334969765893')

couldn't work right but the 

member.roles.find('name', 'Admin')

worked fine. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. I'll see if they have a different prefered method. might try it as an int. I don't work with literals for them often.

If you'd like to see their documentation on it, they use much the same functions as [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get)